# Laravel 9 microservices

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, microservices, laravel-passport, laravel-9

I will be building microservices in Laravel 9 with passport on docker and it will be using database per service and API gateway. All the request will flow through API gateway where it will be authenticated and than it will be forwarded it to the specific microservice.

Please note that only my API gateway will be publicly accessible and other microservices will be not be exposed publicly, they will be used internally.

Also this will be hosted on `AWS` and will be using serverless architecture maybe `Lambda` with `Api Gateway` or `Fargate` not really decided yet.

I have following questions:

1. What grant type is suitable in API gateway architecture?
2. Do I need to write all routes from all microservices in API gateway ? if yes than means that routes will be written twice i.e. in API gateway and individual microservice as well, so how to write the API gateway exactly ?
3. If I want to combine data from different mciroservices into one than should I do that in api gateway?
4. How to authenticate request between microservices as I want it to be secure internally too, should I use the public and private key feature that is provided in passport ? if yes how to verify the keys when request arrives in each microservice?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your System will look something like this:

[System Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxHsJ.png)

**@1 Grant Type**

The grant type is not so much dependent on your API gateway architecture, but more dependent on the types of clients that will use the API. Can you elaborate on that a little more?

**@2 Routing in the API Gateway**

As you said correctly, the API Gateway will be responsible for authentication and routing. One of the main reasons one will choose to implement a microservices architecture, is to decompose a system into smaller, independent services. There is a dependency between the API Gateway and the services, but you can keep this dependency at a manageable level by using wildcards. Eg. all requests that match `/pets/*` go to the "Pets" service.

**@3 Combining Data from multiple services**

The aggregation of data from multiple microservices to assemble a single response should not be done in the API Gateway because this usually is an implementation of some kind of business logic. The API Gateway should not implement business logic, it should authenticate and route requests.

The proper way to implement something like this is a [BFF (Backend for frontend)](https://samnewman.io/patterns/architectural/bff/) which basically is an additional microservice that implements the desired behavior.

It would look something like this: [System with BFF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcpjT.png)

**@4 Internal authentication**

This is also hard to generalize. But you can use the users' authorization token if you like. A way to verify this token is to only check if the token hasn't expired yet in the microservices. This works if the API Gateway takes care that the token is valid in general.

If you need to communicate between your microservices without a user context, then you need to find an alternative approach.

Comment: Hi, Simon thanks for replying. After much R&D I have decided to use monolith as of now. Once my team grows I will rethink and redesign ```microservices``` architecture. Thank you for you help